# BASH - How to run function in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When you run this function, I have a blank screen. Please someone help?

```
#!/bin/bash
function Test(){
  ITEMS=("0" "aaa" "1" "bbb" "2" "ccc")
  SEL=$(whiptail --menu "$menu" 0 0 0 "${ITEMS[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
}

Test 2>/tmp/error.log
```

Thank you to help

Comment: @Mat whiptail is supposed to show a console widgeted screen.

Comment: The problem is the `2>/tmp/error.log` you've redirected the whiptail dialog to the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
```

redirects file descriptor 3 to file descriptor 1, file descriptor one to file descriptor 2, and file descriptor 2 to file descriptor 3

```
2>/tmp/error.log
```

then redirects file descriptor 2 (which fd 1 or stdout has been redirected to) to a file.

Comment: Thank you. There is a way to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but a code review: don't set global variables in a function

```
function Test {
  local items=("0" "aaa" "1" "bbb" "2" "ccc")
  whiptail --menu "$menu" 0 0 0 "${items[@]}" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3
}

sel=$( Test )
echo $sel
```

Also, don't use UPPERCASEVARNAMES -- leave those for the shell

Answer (score 0):

Use `Test` instead of `Test 2>/tmp/error.log`